# Display the admin tag in the comments section of WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want the views of the general manager of the site to be marked with a specific tag in the comments section of my site's articles, which is built with WordPress. But unfortunately, I don't know what kind of code to put so that it can be displayed for me.
My code sample can be seen in the attachment.
Thank you if you have any information in this field.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aPjA.png)

```
                //get the commented user id
                $roles = $_GET["comment-role"];
                echo $roles ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code under the author's name.

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                if (user_can($comment->user_id,'administrator')){ ;?>
                    <span class="badge badge-danger"><?php echo 'admin' ;?></span>
                <?php } else { ;?>
                    <span class="badge badge-primary">user</span>
                <?php } ;?>
```